# How can know binding is alive?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I use spring boot 2.1.x and spring cloud Greenwich.SR5
I want to pre-check whether this binding is alive or not, but I don't know what to do.

How can know source or sink is connected the bindings

Give me a hand.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can view binding status as well as manage it's lifecycle through visualisation and control feature explained [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control).

Basically by adding these dependencies to your POM

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and setting the following property

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bindings
```

. . . you can access the bindings via `http://<host>:<port>/actuator/bindings` url.

Comment: I checked this, but RabbitMQ is down, and the state of the Actuator appears to be running. is it right?
I except RabbitMQ to be down, state is down